# Make OSD notifications via Java

Tags: java, notifications, ubuntu-10.04

I am trying to access the notification bubble in Ubuntu through java

here is my code

```
class TestOSD{

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    String[] cmmd = {"/usr/bin/notify-send -t 10000 \"Hello OSD\" \"This is my first programmatic OSD notification\""};
    System.out.println("This is said : Hello OSD");
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmmd);
}
}
```

I am getting this stacktrace in my command line

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/usr/bin/notify-send -t 10000 "Hello OSD" "This is my first programmatic OSD notification"": java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:460)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:593)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:466)
    at TestOSD.main(TestOSD.java:6)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:148)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:65)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:453)
    ... 3 more
```

Basically i can't understand the overloads of `exec()` method of the Runtime class? Can anybody help me out in this regard?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe the problem is that it's looking for the whole string as the name of the process to start. Try this instead:

```
String[] cmd = { "/usr/bin/notify-send",
                 "-t",
                 "10000",
                 "Hello OSD This is my first programmatic OSD notification"};
```

That should separate out the name of the process from the arguments, and each argument from the rest.

Comment: @Prometheus87: That's using the same overload, but it's passing in a reference to an array of 4 strings, rather than an array with *one* string containing both the program name *and* the command-line arguments.

Comment: You can either use a String[] as Jon does above (one arg per array element), or a plain String containing all of the text as you were trying to in your example. The problem was you combined the two approaches.